# If the bias of an estimator is expressed as a difference, what do you call the ratio of the estimator and true value?

Tags: inference, estimators, unbiased-estimator

If $Bias(\hat{\beta}) = (\beta - \mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}])$, is there a term to describe the quantity $\frac{\mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}]}{\beta}$?

Comment: I’ve never seen that, and I think part of the reason is that many parameters are assumed to be $0$ (at least under null hypotheses). Still, when the value is defined, I wonder when this would be useful, so +1.

Comment: Variance/scale parameters would be a sensible place for it, and I've seen that sort of summary, but I don't know of any standard name for the ratio.

Comment: @user154510 I've never seen an explicit term for it to my recollection, but in a number of situations it's a perfectly sensible thing to consider.